# Diretiva não recebe valor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho essa diretiva:

```
        app.directive('mensagem', function($timeout, $rootScope){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                msg: '='
            },
            template: '<div ng-show="animate && msg" class="alert alert-success animate-show animate-hide" ng-bind="msg"></div>',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                scope.animate = true;
                $timeout(function(){
                    scope.animate = false;
                    scope.msg = undefined;              
                },1500);
            }
        }
    })
```

Tenho um controller chamado 'ArtigosController' com um método 'salvarArtigo'.

```
            $scope.salvaArtigo = function(){
            $http.post(url+'artigo', $scope.artigo).then(function(data){
                if(data.data.sucesso){
                    $rootScope.mensagem = data.data.mensagem;
                    $scope.artigo = {};
                    $state.go('dash');
                }
            })
        }
```

Também tenho um outro controller chamado 'ListaArtigosControler', com um método para ativar ou desativar um artigo.

```
            $scope.ativarArtigo = function(artigo){
            $http.post(url+'remover-artigo/'+artigo.id).then(function(data){
                if(data.data.sucesso){
                    $rootScope.mensagem = data.data.mensagem;
                    $scope.listaArtigos();
                }
            });
        }
```

E por fim, meu html com a diretiva está assim:

```
<mensagem msg="mensagem"></mensagem>
```

Quando eu salvo o artigo, a mensagem do servidor aparece normalmente na diretiva, mas quando eu vou ativar/desativar não aparece mensagem nenhuma. 
Coloquei no html {{mensagem}} e aparece normal, mas o valor não está passando para a diretiva.
Se eu colocar algo do tipo $rootScope.mensagem = 'teste' fora do método de ativar/desativar, ai sim ele passa o valor.

Comment: Pode ser que o Angular tenha se perdido no ciclo de `$digest` dele... coloque esse código logo abaixo do "listaArtigos()".. `if ($scope.$$phase === null) {
                            $scope.$apply();
                        }`

Comment: Coloquei, mas não deu certo não, continua não aparecendo a mensagem :(

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema. A solução foi colocar o $watch dentro da diretiva, ficando dessa forma:

```
        app.directive('mensagem', function($timeout, $rootScope, $compile){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                msg: '='
            },
            template: '<div ng-show="animate && msg" class="alert alert-success animate-show animate-hide" ng-bind="msg"></div>',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                scope.animate = true;
                $timeout(function(){
                    scope.$watch('msg', function(newVal, oldVal){
                        console.log(scope.msg);
                    }, true);

                },1500);
            }
        }
    })
```